# IchigoJam BASIC doesn't require end of double quote when printing a string

Tags: syntax, basic, text-formatting

I'm learning [IchigoJam BASIC](https://fukuno.jig.jp/app/IchigoJam/) for my project. When printing any string I noticed the print function only requires the starting quote character of the double quote. In many other languages the end of the double quote is required, but IchigoJam doesn't show any error. How is this happening?

Output:

```
OK
PRINT "HELLO"
HELLO
OK
PRINT "HELLO
HELLO
OK
PRINT HELLO
0Syntax error
█
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> PRINT HELLO
> 0Syntax error
> ```

The variable name of IchigoJamBASIC is 1 character.

PRINT variable H is executed and ELLO becomes Syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The program size of IchigoJam BASIC is 1k bytes. (It can lengthen the program with LRUN comamnd) Therefore, the end Quotation Marks (") of the character string can be omitted. this can shorten the program.

You can use `?"IchigoJam` instead of `PRINT "IchigoJam"`.